# Swift Cannot assign through subscript: 'peerDeviceSettings' is a get-only property"

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have this declaration in my class:

```
var peerDevice: [String: Any]? 

private var peerDeviceSettings:[String:Any]? {
    get {
        if let settings = peerDevice?["settings"] as? [String:Any] {
            return settings
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Now the problem is if I wish to change peerDeviceSettings, such as this:

```
 fileprivate func set(_ value: Any?, forKey key: Key) {
    if peerDeviceSettings != nil {
        peerDeviceSettings?[key.rawValue] = value
    } 
 }
```

I get an error

```
 Cannot assign through subscript: 'peerDeviceSettings' is a get-only property
```

The point is how do I rearchitect this thing without creating a new mutable variable peerDeviceSettings?

Comment: should be peerDevice?[key.rawValue] = value instead of peerDeviceSettings?[key.rawValue] = value

Comment: No I want it to be peerDeviceSettings. peerDevice contains other key values as well in addition to "settings".

Answer (score 1):

Just add `set (setter)` to the property and handle it there.

```
private var peerDeviceSettings:[String:Any]? {
    get {
        if let settings = peerDevice?["settings"] as? [String:Any] {
            return settings
        }

        return nil
    }
    set {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code seems to be fine, since you're creating links to the nested `settings` dictionary (sounds reasonably)

just add setter:

```
private var peerDeviceSettings: [String: Any]? {
    get {
        if let settings = peerDevice?["settings"] as? [String:Any] {
            return settings
        }

        return nil
    }
    set { 
      if peerDevice == nil {
        peerDevice = [:] // if it's desired behavior
      }
      peerDevice?["settings"] = newValue 
    }

}
```

I'd also suggest getting rid of optionality in `peerDevice`, just initialize it with empty value (if it feets your logic)

Answer (score 1):

You see this error because you declared only getter for your property, you have also add setter

```
    private var peerDeviceSettings:[String:Any]? {
    get {
        if let settings = peerDevice?["settings"] as? [String:Any] {
            return settings
        }

        return nil
    }
    set {
        peerDevice?["settings"] = newValue
    }
}
```

UPDATE: to show how it must be in this certain case

Comment: What does an empty setter do? Also since Swift dictionaries are pass by values, does changing peerDeviceSettings in this class affect peerDevice variable in the class that assigned it to this class?

Comment: it says that variable can be changeable like var someValue {get, set}, when you overriding getter you simply writing a func which will return some value

Comment: this will male `peerDeviceSettings?[key.rawValue] = value` to be not effective

Comment: because in your getter you are accessing data from peerDevice, but set the data to peerDeviceSettings

Comment: Ok lets say if I assign peerDevice from another class mySharedInstance.peerDevice = thisClass.peerDevice, will changes made to peerDeviceSettings in mySharedInstance affect thisClass.peerDevice too?

Comment: of course if your class where this value is declared is singleton

Comment: Ok I was confused about pass by value vs pass by reference. Seems like pass by value(value copy) would apply only in case of function calls.

Comment: There is a problem with empty setter. Updates to dictionary peerDeviceSettings do not work somehow. Had to change code to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You need a setter

```
private var peerDeviceSettings:[String:Any]? {
    get {
        return  peerDevice?["settings"] as? [String:Any]
    }

    set {
        peerDevice?["settings"] = newValue
    }
}
```